# Getting Live Chart data from database

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, livecharts

I have a table named tblWeeklyAudit which has more than one rows data.  I want to read it and show it on the live chart. code is shown below using.

```
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;
using static MAS.clsPUB;

namespace MAS.Windows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Dash.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Dash : Window
    {
        public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
        public string[] Labels { get; set; }
        //public Func<double, string> YFormatter { get; set; }


        public Dash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            double test =0;
            if (CON.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                CON.Close();
            }

            CON.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conDB"].ConnectionString;
            CON.Open();
            CMD = new SqlCommand("select * from tblWeeklyAudit", CON);
            RDR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
            if (RDR.Read())
            {
                 test = Convert.ToDouble(RDR["Defects"]);
            }


            SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { test }
                },  

            };

            Labels = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" };


            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Chart Values are given by this line and I have called the table tblWeeklyAudit and from that defect table. It has several float value rows

```
Values = new ChartValues<double> { test }
```

Comment: thats nice - what is your question/problem?

Comment: I need to know how to get a set of data from a database and show it on the chart. As the code runs it only retrieve one data not all of the data in the table

Comment: You have no loop to read more than 1 item of data - you should start looking there.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is this
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection { new LineSeries { Values = new ChartValues<double> { 2,5,3,4 } }, };

The values should be like the above cannot add one by one

Comment: But you only read 1 row of data from your query! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the double values to a `List<double>` that you then pass to the constructor of the `ChartValues<double>` class:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    List<double> allValues = new List<double>();
    if (CON.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        CON.Close();
    }

    CON.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conDB"].ConnectionString;
    CON.Open();
    CMD = new SqlCommand("select * from tblWeeklyAudit", CON);
    RDR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
    while (RDR.Read())
    {
        allValues.Add(Convert.ToDouble(RDR["Defects"]));
    }

    SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double>(allValues)
                }
            };

    Labels = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" };


    DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read more than one line do the following:

```
var List<double> allValues = new List<double>();

if (RDR.HasRows)
        {
            while (RDR.Read())
            {
               allValues.Add(Convert.ToDouble(RDR["Defects"]));
            }
        }
```

Then use allValues in your SeriesCollection.

Comment: could i know how to add `allValues` to **here**

`SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { **Here** }
                }

            };`